# Ruby Nokogiri - XPATH using URL

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have this table:

```
 <tr>
      <td><b>Amount</b></td>
      <td><b>Due Date</b></td>
      <td"><b>Link</b></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
  <td>02/13/2012</td>
  <td>$81.66</td>
  <td><a onclick="javascript:window.open('/cso/displaypdfbill?selectedBillkey=449409587','_blank');" href="javascript: void(0);">View Bill</a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>01/13/2012</td>
  <td>$181.66</td>
  <td><a onclick="javascript:window.open('/cso/displaypdfbill?selectedBillkey=543409587','_blank');" href="javascript: void(0);">View Bill</a></td>

</tr>
```

I am looping through the table and extracting the `Bill` key in each row.  I removed the `Billkey` and stored it into a variable.

```
BillKey = 449409587
```

What I want is to get the `<tr>` where that `BillKey` is located:

So I should have:

```
2/13/2012      81.86     View Bill
```

I am having trouble writing the XPATH to get the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
   string(table/tr
            [td/a/@onclick
                  [substring
                    (.,
                     string-length()
                   - 21
                    )
                  =
                   $vEnding
                  ]
            ]
         )
```

**where $vEnding must be substituted by the string**: `"=449409587','_blank');"`

So, the complete XPath expression after this substitution is:

```
   string(table/tr
            [td/a/@onclick
                  [substring
                    (.,
                     string-length()
                   - 21
                    )
                  =
                   "=449409587','_blank');"
                  ]
            ]
         )
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

**This XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vEnding">=449409587','_blank');</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "string(table/tr
            [td/a/@onclick
                  [substring
                    (.,
                     string-length()
                   - 21
                    )
                  =
                   $vEnding
                  ]
            ]
         )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one wrapped in a single top element `table`):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Amount</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Due Date</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Link</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02/13/2012</td>
        <td>$81.66</td>
        <td>
            <a onclick=
            "javascript:window.open('/cso/displaypdfbill?selectedBillkey=449409587','_blank');" href="javascript: void(0);">View Bill</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01/13/2012</td>
        <td>$181.66</td>
        <td>
            <a onclick=
            "javascript:window.open('/cso/displaypdfbill?selectedBillkey=543409587','_blank');" href="javascript: void(0);">View Bill</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**evaluates the XPath expression and copies to the output the result of the evaluation**:

```
    02/13/2012
    $81.66

        View Bill
```

Comment: I can't get this one to work.  you have $vEnding = =449409587','_blank', but I just have $vEnding = 449409587.  Is there a way to just do it where the onclick contains 449409587?

Comment: @user1198316: Yes, in XPath 1.0 we are implementing the XPath 2.0-only function `ends-with($s, $p)` with `substring($s, string-length() - string-length($p) +1) = string-length($p)` . So, in any case you must get the `string-length()` of the identifying ending string and put it into your expression.

Comment: @user1198316: The evaluation of the XPath expression in my answer on the provided XML document (as in my  answer) produces the reported results. I always test the code and I actually copy/paste the results from running this code.